# Info.plist. How I can I specify multiple executables?

Tags: java, macos, info.plist

I figured out some of the basics to writing an Info.plist file to package a mac application. I have run into a somewhat annoying issue. I have a jar file that is the main entry point of the application. The plist file has a launcher set as it's CFBundleExecutable. This launcher opens the jar file.

There are 2 jar files. The jar 1 is called by launcher and checks for updates and performs them. Then when it is done, jar 1 executes jar 2. Once jar 2 executes, the information given by the plist file seems to disappear. The CFBundleIcon and CFBundleDisplayName go back to default java.

I can guess that this is occurring because the launcher script is no longer running and all plist settings are set to that launcher. How can I fix this as painlessly as possible? Can I nest another .app for jar 2 within that .app? Is there an Info.plist solution? It's not breaking any functionality, it just looks unprofessional.

The package contents are 
App -> Contents -> MacOs -> [jar1, jar2, launcher, sharedAccessFiles]

I am calling jar 2 from jar 1 using using:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pathToJava "-jar", pathToJar2, "-Xdock:icon=" + pathToIcon, "-Xdock:name=AppName");
```

This doesn't seem to change anything. the top bar still says java and the icon remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch JAR #2, use the following parameters:

> -Xdock:icon=pathToIconFile Sets the icon displayed in the Dock. By default, OS X displays a generic Java icon unless you specify
>   otherwise. You only need to use this for applications launched from
>   the command line or from a JAR file. Double-clickable application
>   bundles designate their icon in the Info.plist file.
>
> -Xdock:name=applicationName Sets the name to display in the Dock and in the menu bar. By default, OS X displays the fully qualified name of
>   the main class unless you specify otherwise. You need to use this only
>   for applications launched from the command line or from a JAR file.
>   Double-clickable application bundles get the appropriate name from the
>   Info.plist file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/Java_VMOptionsRef/Articles/JavaVirtualMachineOptions.html

Comment: As my edit shows, java ProcessBuilder calls the jar with the vm options you are specifying.